# CamelExchangeException Invalid Correlation Key on exchange header

Tags: apache-camel, aggregate, correlation

Apache Camel is throwing Invalid Correlation Key exception when trying to aggregate messages from my AWS SQS queue. 
The messages were placed in the queue using ZipSplitter and they all appear in the queue with matching "parentId" values (which I added using a random uuid as part of the splitting -I've tried CamelSourceFile as well).  I get the Exception repeatedly until the retries are exhausted.

My aggregate expression:

```
from(--queue--).aggregate(header("parentId"), customAggregationStrategy).completionTimeout(3000).processor(new Processor() {...}.to(--next queue--);
```

There is no logging emitted from my customAggregationStrategy nor from any of the subsequent processors.  It fails to aggregate:

```
... DeadLetterChannel - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ...). On Delivery attempt: 0 caught ...CamelExchangeException: Invalid correlation key. Exchange[ID...]
```

The delivery attempt is 0 through 9 for my retry attempts.

The infuriating thing is that the code works everywhere but locally...which you think would narrow things down, but neither the exception nor anything else logged sheds any light onto what is going on here.

Comment: Are you sure the header is there for every exchange? Could you check it? For example adding logging onException block to your route `onException(Throwable.class).to("log:exceptionLogged?showAll=true");` to be sure. If header is there, which Camel version you are using?

Comment: Yeah, the headers are dumped out (logged) before and after a processor that adds the custom header.  "parentId" is added prior to aggregation (and it is currently working in our test environment), but it does not seem to matter whether I use the custom header or one of Camels' headers (CamelFileAbsolutePath which contains my zip file).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Camel simple language when expressing the correlation key, ie:

```
.aggregate(simple("${headers.parentId}", customAggregationStrategy)
```

This way, the exceptions **might** be silently ignored ?

Did you activate Camel tracer (http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) to analyse your exchanges and ease the debugging ?

I suspect you have an Exchange which does NOT have the "parentId" header. If you want to skip them, just activate the `ignoreInvalidCorrelationKeys` option (see http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html)

Comment: Thanks @TacheDeChoco, I will give the simple syntax a shot.  Ignoring the InvalidCorrelationKeys works insofar as it doesn't throw the error, but the file does not get ingested properly.

Comment: So the simple language did not work.  I think there must be something with my environment -given that it works in other environments.  It's crazy because I don't want to "fix" it locally if it's not exhibiting the same behavior in other env...just bizarre.